Is bidirectional module federation possible between a webpack project and a vite project?
I'm investigating webpack's module federation and the potential for allowing separate teams to choose their own frameworks and still share UI elements on one website. I have set up a number of different projects to test module federation with different build tools.
What I have tested is:

webpack remote with webpack host (works)
webpack remote with rspack host (works)
webpack remote with vite host (works when webpack is configured to output esm modules)
rspack remote with webpack host (works)
vite host with vite remote (works)
vite host with webpack remote (does not work)

I'm able to get module federation to work when I have a webpack remote that is configured to use esm modules that are being hosted by a vite host. However, with the same configuration, I cannot get a webpack host to host modules from a vite remote. When I have a webpack remote and a webpack host both configured to output esm modules, I get the same behavior where the webpack host will not load the modules.
There error being output in the console on the webpack host is:

Uncaught Syntax Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module
My webpack.config.js file for the webpack host is:
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);import path from 'path';
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
import { VueLoaderPlugin } from 'vue-loader';
import * as fs from 'fs';
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

let packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json').toString());

let deps = { ...packageJson.dependencies, ...packageJson.devDependencies };

export default {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        port: 8000,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js/,
                type: "javascript/auto",
                resolve: {
                    fullySpecified: false,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            // this will apply to both plain `.css` files
            // AND `<style>` blocks in `.vue` files
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                    //{
                    //  loader: 'css-loader',
                    //  options: { }
                    //}
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        //module: true,
        //library: { type: 'module' },
        //chunkFormat: 'module',
        //chunkLoading: 'import',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        uniqueName: 'webpack-client'
    },
    target: 'es2020',
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true
    },
    //externalsType: "module",
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
            //template: './index.ejs',
            //inject: false
        }),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "host",
            library: { type: 'module' },
            remotes: {
              web_common: "web_common@http://localhost:8082/remoteEntry.js",
              vite_remote: "vite_remote@http://localhost:8083/assets/remoteEntry.js"
            },
            shared: {
                ...deps,
                vue: {
                    eager: true,
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps.vue
                },
            }
        })
    ],
    //optimization: { splitChunks: { chunks: 'initial' } }
};

My tsconfig.json for my webpack host looks like:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    //"module": "ES2022",
    //"target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",




    //"target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    //"moduleResolution": "bundler",
    //"allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    //"noEmit": true,
    //"jsx": "preserve",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  }
}


My vite.config.ts for my vite remote looks like:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    federation({
      name: 'vite_remote',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './moduleC': './src/components/moduleC.vue'
      },
      shared: [
        'vue'
      ]
    })
  ],
  build: {
    target: 'ES2022'
  }
})

My tsconfig.json for my vite remote looks like:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}


I'd like to be able to have bidirectional module federation working between a webpack project and a vite project. If this is not possible, I'd like to understand why it is not and why I am getting the error that I am seeing in the console for the webpack host.
